# iterator.get_next() returns byte array / iterator.get_next() cannot be assigned to multiple values without eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have a problem where I try to create a [tf.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)
from a `tfrecord` file via [tf.data.TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset).

```
def parse_function(example_proto):
# Defaults are not specified since both keys are required. 
keys_to_features={
      'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([1024*1024],tf.int64),
      'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1024*1024],tf.int64)
}
features = tf.parse_example([example_proto],keys_to_features)
label = features['label']
image = features['image']
label = tf.reshape(label,(1024,1024))
image = tf.reshape(image,(1024,1024))
return image,label

def make_batch(batch_size):
    filenames = ["train.tfrecords"]
    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames).repeat()
    dataset.map(map_func=parse_function,num_parallel_calls=batch_size)
    dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    image , label  = iterator.get_next()
    return image , label
```

This caused the error:

> Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

So I changed : `image , label  = iterator.get_next()` 
to : `next_elem  = iterator.get_next()`

With this I could execute this code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess: 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
next_elem   = sess.run( make_batch(1))
```

However, next_elem is a array of bytes instead of a tuple with shape ([1024,1024],[1024,1024]).

Answer (score 1):

So turned out the error was just a misunderstanding on my part.

```
dataset.map(map_func=parse_function,num_parallel_calls=batch_size)
dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

does not manipulate the dataset itself see: [Iterator.get_next() returning a tensor of shape ()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13508)

You have to actually assignt the dataset resulting form those operation to the dataset again like so:
`dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parse_function,num_parallel_calls=batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)`

This actually also resolved  the `iterator.get_next()` issue. So I changed `next_elem  = iterator.get_next()` back to: `image , label  = iterator.get_next()`

and with this follwing code works as expected: `with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    image , label  = sess.run( make_batch(1))`